# Rook error: Error in inherits(app, "RhttpdApp")

Tags: r, r-rook-package

I have some apps which have been running into my office for weeks. In the last days, sometimes, I receive in the R console the following message:

```
Error in inherits(app, "RhttpdApp") : 
  no function to return from, jumping to top level
```

Do you know where this error is generated and any possible cause? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not inside a function and you use `return`. For example running this reproduce your error:

```
{
  return(0)
}
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
```

I guees you have something like :

```
 if (!inherits(app,'RhttpdApp'))
   {.. return(...)}
```

Comment: thanks a lots!! I'll investigate. Anyway, I'm not using that anywhere, that's why I asked for `where this error is generated`. I started when I did a data refresh with some `data.table` in place of `data.frame` and `IDate` in place of `Date`.

Comment: @Michele hum..I see. If you use `git` (or any other version control), maybe you can go back to previous versions of your code and trace the exact portion of code that produce the error. `options(error=browser)` can help also.

Comment: yes, I'd probably need that. Thanks again